# No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, firemonkey-fm3

I'm getting following errors while trying to build a distribution version of my firemonkey app.

> [PAClient Error] Error: E0776 2020-07-21 16:50:36.073 xcodebuild[2035:200954] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/1d/j6b25yvj6wsg95yjm4m4p3dm0000gn/T/ExpenseClaims_2020-07-21_16-50-36.072.xcdistributionlogs'.
>
> [PAClient Error] Error: E0776 error: exportArchive: No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive
>
> [PAClient Error] Error: E0776 Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive" UserInfo=
>
> {NSLocalizedDescription=No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive}

Comment: Still no answers? I see this problem with no teamID was asked on the Embarcadero community forums 3 years ago, and also doesn't have an answer. Is it so rare that there isn't an answer? Surely Embarcadero, who wrote the PAClient, should be able to explain why that error is shown, and what values in one of the project files needs to be updated to include the teamID?

Comment: An issue was created in Embarcadero's Quality Central, and their first response was "does this happen in 10.4.1?". We've confirmed it still happens in that build and we've yet to see any other communication. This error seems common, as there are other posts about it for other development environments, and it generally seems to be an XCode build problem. Trouble is, Firemonkey deployment happens by the PAClient sending information to the PAServer as instructions for the XCode processes, so that would have to be something internal to the Embarcadero programs.

Answer (score 0):

Still hit this issue in 10.4.2; the message looks more like it is related to a macOS build even though an iOS build is selected. I added macOS to the project configure some Application Store settings (did not use them) then delete macOS from my project

After this the build was ok

Reopened an instance https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-33830